# How do I correctly setup the scss file watcher in PhpStorm?

Tags: sass, phpstorm

I have it working, but with these settings it takes quite a while until the change comes through in PhpStorm. If I get rid of the `../css/` part of the argument string then it creates/updates the css file in the same directory as the scss file is in, but does it immediately. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using PhpStorm 6.0.1 on OS X 10.8.3

[image: My current settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual: "In the Output Paths text box, specify the files where the transpiler stores its output: the resulting source code, source maps, and dependencies. **Based on this settings, PhpStorm detects files generated** through transpilation."

Answer (score 57):

as it's mentioned in the previous answer, you have to set up the Output paths option accordingly.
Like:

```
Arguments: --no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Working directory: $FileDir$

Output Paths: $FileParentDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Now output paths matches the scss output directory, so that the IDE knows where to look for output and what it looks like

Comment: Thank you, but I figured it out not long after asking. The previous answer is my own.

Answer (score 27):

I recommend using **node-sass** it's **10+ times faster**

```
 npm install -g node-sass
```

Program :

```
/usr/local/bin/node-sass
```

Arguments :

```
$FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Output Paths :

```
$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```

[image]

Edit :

If you want the css file compressed, use that for the Arguments :

```
--output-style compressed $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Comment: The  official SASS website says the npm version is the slowest implementation though. it says "However, please note that this will install the pure JavaScript implementation of Sass, which runs somewhat slower than the other options listed here"

Answer (score 15):

For anyone uses node-sass in Windows Env, here you go,

> Program:

Windows

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-sass.cmd
```

Linux

```
/usr/local/bin/node-sass
```

> Arguments (Windows):

```
$FileName$ $ProjectFileDir$\dist\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

> Output paths for refresh(windows):

```
$ProjectFileDir$\dist\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Comment: In case you need sourcemap, simply add `--sourceMap=$FileDir$` to the end of `Arguments`. This will tell node-sass to output sourcemap file to the same folder that contains your scss file.

Comment: Hi, I am working on Mac. I made a file watch in phpstorm 2016.1 for .scss, with scss compiler, it works well.

Since node-sass is much faster, I installed node-sass globally, and changed the program setting from "/usr/bin/scss" to "/usr/local/bin/node-sass". But it doesn't work in phpstorm, instead, it always shows spinner which reminder me it is compiling.

Do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: @Ng2-Fun I am not familiar with OSX but seems like the path is different? ``/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass`` ?

Comment: when I do "which node-sass", it showed me the same as you posted for Linux. When I changed to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass`, it told me permission denied.
Which PHPStorm version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

In Phpstorm 7 use

Arguments: 
--no-cache --update $FileName$:$FileParentDir$/path/to/css/dir/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Output Paths: 
$FileParentDir$/path/to/css/dir/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

This found.